# Rand() dentro do for

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte condição de FOR:

```
<? for($i=0; $i<=9; $i++){ ?>
    <input type="button" value="<?=$i?>" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)" class="btn btn-default">  
<? } ?>
```

Gostaria que ao invés de exibir 0, 1, 2, 3... exibisse randomicamente.
Como posso fazer isto?

Comment: E o problema com o `rand()`/`mt_rand()`?

Comment: Não sei explicar, precisava que dentro dos dígitos numéricos, exibisse randomicamente...

Comment: `value="<?=mt_rand(1,10)?>"` qual o problema nisso?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/b5i7gt

Answer (score -2):

Neste exemplo gera números entre 0 e 100, é só alterar o intervalo que queres em `rand(MIN, MAX)`

```
<? for($i=0; $i<=9; $i++){ 
      srand(make_seed());?>
    <input type="button" value="<?=rand(0, 100)?>" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)" class="btn btn-default">  
<? } ?>
```

Comment: Já tentei dessa forma, ele repete os numeros.. :(

Comment: usa com srand(make_seed());  primiero, vê como está agora